# exit code 9009 executing command from within ms build

Tags: windows, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to include a webpack build step in a test.csproj, to "build" some javascript code.

The javascript code lives at "D:\js_code". When I enter

```
D:\js_code>webpack
```

in the command line, everything works fine and the expected results are produced.

To include the command in the test.csproj, I used

```
 <Target Name="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
         ... 
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command     ... />
    <Exec Command="D:\js_code\webpack.exe"/>
  </Target>
```

Where `...` are placeholders for other tags and commands that are totally valid and produce correct results and were therefore left out here.

When I build test.csproj, I get

> The command "D:\js_code\webpack.exe" exited with code 9009

same with just

```
<Exec Command="D:\js_code\webpack"/>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try running `webpack.exe` from the command line as well to check for any errors. Alternatively, run `msbuild /v:diag > diag.log` to get a diagnostic log that will show webpack's output as well.
2. Webpack will need to run in the directory the js code is in, sou you probably need

   ```
   <Exec Command="webpack.exe" WorkingDirectory="D:\js_code" />
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of your two suggestions helped. I can run webpack from the command line in the correct folder and everything works fine. And when I explicitely set the working directory, I still get 9009.

Comment: and you are sure that `webpack.exe` exists in this directory at the time of this build step?

Comment: I have just realized that I made stupid mistake and can confirm now, that your 2. suggestion actually works for me. Thanks again.